# Can we drop CSS property"-webkit-scrollbar" from a single node?

Tags: html, css, webkit

How can I drop the CSS property `::-webkit-scrollbar` from a single HTML element?

In my CSS file, I have this code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:  6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: blue;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {    
    background-color: #d4dee8;
    width: 6px;
}
```

It will replace every scrollbar with webkit scrollbars. But there are two places where I don't need webkit scrollbar, I need normal scrollbars instead.

HTML file:

```
<td class="viewDialogLabel" height="21" style="width:156px;padding:0px"> 
    <!-- Inner elements --->
</td>
```

Here, I need to change class `viewDialogLabel` to normal scrollbars.

How do I get this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebKit supports the handy CSS value [`initial`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/initial), which sets properties back to the values they would have had if no styles applied to the page.

So, you can reset the `::-webkit-scrollbar` values you’ve set like this:

```
.viewDialogLabel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    background-color:initial;
}
.viewDialogLabel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:initial;
    width: initial;
}
.viewDialogLabel::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: initial;
}
.viewDialogLabel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {    
    background-color: initial;
    width: initial;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/

---

WebKit also supports [the `:not()` selector](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Anot%28%29), so I would have thought the following amendment to your original CSS would prevent the custom scrollbars from applying to that table cell:

```
:not(.viewDialogLabel)::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:  6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
:not(.viewDialogLabel)::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 6px;
}
:not(.viewDialogLabel)::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: blue;
}
:not(.viewDialogLabel)::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #d4dee8;
    width: 6px;
}
```

However, it doesn’t work for me in Chrome 16 — the custom scrollbar styles aren’t applied at all (see http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/1/). I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong, if you just can’t combine these selectors, or if this is a WebKit bug.

As per your suggested edit removing the `td` selectors from the CSS, this seems to be working in Chrome 24 at least: http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/2/

Comment: I am also using Chrome 16, the custom scrollbar styles aren’t applied at all

Comment: I made a correction in selectors see [http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/2/ ]. But CSS value initial,  is not working as it expected, because when I give 'initial' to all fields where i need to override webkit scrolls to normal, webkit scrollbars are disappeared. But normal scrollbar failed to replace  webkit scrollbars. It's only transparent background in scrollbar area, see [http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/3/ ].

Comment: Good lord, yes, I see what you mean about `initial`. That’s odd — it worked fine for table cells with `overflow: hidden;`, but for textareas, it seems not. Then again, the `:not()` solution seems to work fine with just the class selector inside `:not()`.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr and http://jsfiddle.net/uVGKr/3/ appear to be broken now in Chrome 22. I'm seeing blank space where the default scrollbar should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a more accurate selector:

```
.new-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* ... */
}
```

Then, only elements with the class *new-scrollbar* will have the custom scrollbars.

Or you can try to override the properties in specific elements:

```
.old-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: none;
}

.old-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}

/* ... */
```

Also try it with different properties / values.

Comment: Its not possible, because It will take plenty of time  to restructure(both in Js file and CSS file) it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing these properties from those two elements you can specify a separate class or ids for these two elements and override the -webkit-scrollbar styles with new ones

Comment: Can you please show me a demo on override the -webkit-scrollbar styles with new ones.

Comment: Here it is:
#your-id {
    width:  auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: none;
}
Now you can put this id in your tags whos styles you want to override